# SQL Select without duplicates, and conditional choice of the proper duplicate to keep

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, duplicates, greatest-n-per-group

I have a readonly table with a list of products,
and I need to avoid selecting duplicates based on the serial number ('serial').
When I have a duplicate I want to select the duplicate which 'label' first letter is between A and J.

Here are my data and my try to get a selection without duplicates:

```
CREATE TABLE products(id INT, serial VARCHAR(25), label VARCHAR(50) , type VARCHAR(25));

INSERT INTO products(id, serial, label, type)
    VALUES
        ( 1, '111', 'A1', 'computer'),
        ( 2, '222', 'B2', 'computer'),
        ( 3, '333', 'Z3', 'computer'),
        ( 4, '333', 'D4', 'computer'),
        ( 5, '555', 'E5', 'computer'),
        ( 6, '666', 'X6', 'computer'),
        ( 7, '777', 'G7', 'computer'),
        ( 8, '777', 'Y7', 'computer'),
        ( 9, '888', 'I8', 'computer'),
        (10, '999', 'J9', 'screen'),
        (11, '777', 'G7bis', 'computer'),
        (12, '666', 'X6bis', 'computer');


SELECT COUNT(serial) OVER(PARTITION BY serial) as nbserial, *
FROM products
where type='computer' and nbserial=1 or
(nbserial>1 and LEFT(label, 1) between 'A' and 'J')
;
```

I have several problems: here I cannot define a condition about nbserial in the where clause.
And if there are 3 duplicates, I need to select a line which verifies the condition: label first letter is between A and J.
And if there are several duplicates, but none verifies the condition (firstletter between A and J), then select any line.

example of expected result:
(no serial duplicate, and if possile label starts with letter between A and J)

```
    ( 1, '111', 'A1', 'computer'),
    ( 2, '222', 'B2', 'computer'),
    ( 4, '333', 'D4', 'computer'),
    ( 5, '555', 'E5', 'computer'),
    ( 6, '666', 'X6', 'computer'),
    ( 7, '777', 'G7', 'computer'),
    ( 9, '888', 'I8', 'computer'),
    (10, '999', 'J9', 'screen'),
```

How can I do that with a SELECT, and I cannot change the table content ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` and a conditional sort:

```
select *
from (
    select p.*,
        row_number() over(
            partition by serial
            order by case when left(label, 1) between 'A' and 'J' then 0 else 1 end, id
        ) rn
    from products p
) p
where rn = 1
```

Or better yet, use `distinct on` in Postgres:

```
select distinct on (serial) p.*
from products p
order by serial, (left(label, 1) between 'A' and 'J') desc, id
```

This gives one row per `serial`, and prioritizes labels whose first letter is between "A" and "J". When there are ties, the row with the least `id` is retained.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=80451052118a6b2865550ab26269d860)**:

```
id | serial | label | type    
-: | :----- | :---- | :-------
 1 | 111    | A1    | computer
 2 | 222    | B2    | computer
 4 | 333    | D4    | computer
 5 | 555    | E5    | computer
 6 | 666    | X6    | computer
 7 | 777    | G7    | computer
 9 | 888    | I8    | computer
10 | 999    | J9    | screen
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Very intersting.